# Selenium webdriver - relative xpath, get element with text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation

I am using Selenium webdriver with java.

I am trying to find elements in drop down lists, can`t access it by exact id/name/xpath because those are dynamic elements, so I tried to locate it by relative xpath, and it works but not fully, please see image below:

[IMAGE ON IMGUR (CANT POST IMAGES YES)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2peCk.png)

As you can see on top left, there is a drop down overlay with 3 options, ALL/ACTIVE/INACTIVE, now I managed to locate all 3 of them by using relative xpath as shown on image:

```
//*[@class="cdk-overlay-pane"]//*[@class="mat-option-text"]
```

But how to now get one element (out of 3 in this case) that got specific text, for example "Active" ? I tried following:

```
//*[@class="cdk-overlay-pane"]//*[@class="mat-option-text"]//*[contains(text(),'Active')]
```

But it does not find anything, any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
//*[@class="cdk-overlay-pane"]//span[@class="mat-option-text" and normalize-space(text())="All"]
```

Comment: Indeed it is much better solution, I used contains, because of the white spaces (did not realise I could remove it the way you did, thank you)

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, search for text using "contains"

Here`s working relative xpath in my case:

```
//*[@class="cdk-overlay-pane"]//*[contains(text(), 'All')]
```

It would return element with "All" text that is located within drop down panel.

Comment: just for info, if you have 2 texts: 'All' 'All active', you will match 2 elements. Better to do equals of string, just to normalize the white space.